# Esri Silverlight control Pan/Zoom from code

Tags: silverlight, esri

I have trouble getting Map behave properly when calling `ZoomToResolution` and `PanTo`
I need to be able to Zoom into specific coordinate and center map.

The only way I got it working is by removing animations:

```
this.MapControl.ZoomDuration = new TimeSpan(0);
this.MapControl.PanDuration = new TimeSpan(0);
```

Otherwise if I make call like this:

```
control.MapControl.ZoomToResolution(ZoomLevel);
control.MapControl.PanTo(MapPoint());
```

It does one or another (i.e. pan or zoom, but not both). If (after animation) I call this code second time (map already zoomed or panned to needed position/level) - it does second part.

Tried this:

```
control.MapControl.ZoomToResolution(ZoomLevel, MapPoint());
```

Same issue, internally it calls above commands

So, my only workaround right now is to set Zoom/Pan duration to 0. And it makes for bad UX when using mouse.

I also tried something like this:

```
this.MapControl.ZoomDuration = new TimeSpan(0);
this.MapControl.PanDuration = new TimeSpan(0);
control.MapControl.ZoomToResolution(ZoomLevel);
control.MapControl.PanTo(MapPoint());
this.MapControl.ZoomDuration = new TimeSpan(750);
this.MapControl.PanDuration = new TimeSpan(750);
```

Which seems to be working, but then mouse interaction becomes "crazy". Mouse scroll will make map jump and zoom to random places.

Is there known solution?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the second operation replaces the previous one. You would have to wait for one to complete before starting the next one. But that probably doesn't give the effect you want.
Instead zoom to an extent, and you'll get the desired behavior. If you don't have the extent but only center and resolution, you can create one using the following:

var zoomToExtent = new Envelope(point.X - resolution * MapControl.ActualWidth/2, point.Y, point.X + resolution * MapControl.ActualWidth/2, point.Y);

Btw it's a little confusing in your code that you call your resolution "ZoomLevel". I assume this is a map resolution, and not a level number right? The esri map control doesn't deal with service-specific levels, but is agnostic to the data's levels and uses a more generic "units per pixels" resolution value.

Comment: ZoomLevel is just a number I "picked" that looks correct. So, yeah, it's not level number... I will try zoomToExtent. Is there anything like "async" operations with esri control? I don't mind chaining calls if needed, but what is the syntax? Definitely don't want to block UI thread..
I'm converting from Bing Maps control, thats why it might look confusing, trying to keep code as close as possible. I already created my custom control that wraps esri map and was able to make almost all I need MVVM-friendly..

Comment: This works, but there is no animations.. Any way to make it animate nicely like Bing maps does? So, for example if I'm at the certain point/zoom and need to move to another point - would be nice if map zooms out while panning and then zooms in into new point. This would give use better UX because it will show where new location is..

Comment: There should be animation. Did you keep the zoom duration at 0 (if so, get rid of it). However note that if extent you're going to is very far away, the animation will be skipped to avoid panning and loading tiles all across the world. There's no async support but you can built that on top of the event (google event to async). The new esri .net API has this though.